# React Native 0.64 Hermes iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Всем привет; Начал работать с новым движком в связке с reanimated 2.
Release версию iPA практически нереально собрать, так как долго компилируется 1ч и больше;
Mac i9, 16 ОЗУ. Да дело однозначно не в этом, думаю это связано с тем, что высокая оптимизация и он ужимается максимально. Эта 1 из проблем.
2-я проблема, жутко лагает, подвисает на симуляторах и реальных устройствах. Что крайне усложняет жизнь. На JavaScriptCore все прекрасно летает. Но к большому сожалению его не могу использовать.
Есть идеи?